# Merge columns in Pandas based on date criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
In[337]: df
Out[337]: 
                2013      2014      2015
2013-01-31  0.705935  0.983307  0.714397
2013-05-31  0.492020  0.532103  0.897666
2013-09-30  0.187822  0.779611  0.774774
2014-01-31  0.789511  0.383665  0.353669
2014-05-31  0.347580  0.540767  0.732863
2014-09-30  0.382052  0.960596  0.917685
2015-01-31  0.106079  0.622926  0.302552
2015-05-31  0.282134  0.195239  0.968098
2015-09-30  0.185158  0.410412  0.048988
```

I am trying to merge the data into a new column based on the year in the index.  eg "for row 2014-09-30 select data from column '2014', 0.960596"

```
Out[345]: 
                data
2013-01-31  0.705935
2013-05-31  0.492020
2013-09-30  0.187822
2014-01-31  0.383665
2014-05-31  0.540767
2014-09-30  0.960596
2015-01-31  0.302552
2015-05-31  0.968098
2015-09-30  0.048988
```

Is there a way to neatly automate this with an if loop or otherwise?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the dates are parsed you can do this:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row[str(row.name.year)], axis=1)
```

**Edit:**

This was what I was looking for:

```
pd.Series(
    df.lookup(
        row_labels=df.index,
        col_labels=df.index.year.astype(str)
    ),
    index=df.index
)
```

The [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html#pandas.DataFrame.lookup) method gives you for each given row label the value at the corresponding column label. This function is heaps faster (if I resample the dataframe to hourly, the first method is timed with ~3.5s while the `lookup` method finishes in ~20ms).

Comment: +1, very nice solution. Can you add your benchmark to the answer? Also, I think for others it could be useful to include how to convert a Series to the desired dataframe, e.g. `pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(...), columns=['data'])`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# reproduce test data
> df = pd.DataFrame([[datetime.date(2013,01,31), 0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [datetime.date(2014,01,31), 0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [datetime.date(2015,01,31), 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]], columns=['date', '2013', '2014', '2015']).set_index('date')
> df.index.name = None
> df
            2013  2014  2015
2013-01-31   0.1   0.2   0.3
2014-01-31   0.1   0.2   0.3
2015-01-31   0.1   0.2   0.3

# extract year and use it as a key for the row object
> df.apply(lambda r: r[str(r.name.year)], axis=1)
2013-01-31    0.1
2014-01-31    0.2
2015-01-31    0.3

# create the desired dataframe
> df_new = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda r: r[str(r.name.year)], axis=1), index=df.index, columns=['data'])
> df_new
            data
2013-01-31   0.1
2014-01-31   0.2
2015-01-31   0.3
```

Comment: Close one ;). By the way, you can parse the data from the question using `df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO("""...""", parse_dates=True, delim_whitespace=True))`.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that.

Comment: @filmor: By the way, I had to write `u"""..."""` to make it work.

Comment: Thanks v much for both of these! The function above works for me.

I'm still a beginner, to help me understand:
1. I assume column names always need to be the year only 'yyyy' for this to work
2. r.name.year pulls the year from the row name.  why is it I cannot seperately run df.index.name.year, what does the name attribute refer to?
3. what do you mean by dates being 'parsed'? fyi i created them using 
    `daterange = pd.date_range('20130101','20160101', freq='4M')
    df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(9,3),index=daterange,columns=['2013','2014','2015'])`

Comment: 1) Yes, the years your `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` objects contain have to match your column headings. 2) `r.name` **is** the index of the corresponding row object, e.g. a `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` object in your case. 3) Well for us SO people who want to help you it is important to insert your data somehow into our python. But what we get is a string representation of the dataframe and not the dataframe you have in memory. That's why we have to 'parse' the string to reconstruct a valid dataframe again. With `parse_dates=True` the index is not interpreted as plain string, but as timestamps.

Comment: Understood.  I'll try to submit my data on to here in dataframe form as much as possible.
If I wanted the key to be )row.date.year +1) can I use df.apply(lambda r: r[str(r.name.year+1)], axis=1)?  This returns a key error if there is no column name '2016'. I don't mind having an NaN in this case.

Comment: Yes that works if the column exists. Just put an if around. `df.apply(lambda r: r[str(r.name.year + 1)] if str(r.name.year + 1) in df.columns else np.NaN` (something like this)